# Top and bottom of outlet sparking when plugging in charger

Tags: electrical

I recently replaced some older receptacles with these: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JC1SZD9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JC1SZD9)

One of the outlets sparks when I plug something into it, such as a battery charger. Now it's not like I haven't seen that before, but what I'm wondering about is:

1. Indoor humidity is about 50%, so not dry.
2. No battery is in the charger when plugging in and there is still a spark.
3. Most curious is that the top AND bottom outlets spark (the whole receptacle). Usually it seems like only the outlet in use would spark.
4. I haven't checked all the outlets I've replaced, but there are others that don't seem to do this.

Is this anything to be concerned about beyond the "normal" spark here and there when a device is plugged in?

Comment: ...is there any reason you're buying receptacles off Amazon, instead of at your local hardware or home improvement store?

Comment: I wanted commercial grade for a firmer hold and decora style. These were all I could find anywhere. I installed some "local store" outlets and brand new they had vacuum cords sagging out of them.

Comment: Try using any extension cord you have, now plug the charger in the extension cord and then plug the extension cord in the wall outlet. Report. Assumption is you got a bad apple wall socket, so the baldes from the charger plug do not tightly fit = arching.

Comment: Please also try plugging the extension cord into the outlet first then plug the battery charger into the extension cord while watching the outlet. If the outlet still sparks, there's definitely something wrong with the outlet.

Comment: If both outlets(top and bottom) spark when using only one, that is a problem.  Usually sparks are cause by loose connections, either just touching when plugging in(okay), or a loose connection inside(bad) or wires not screwed in tightly enough(fixable).

Answer (score 3):

What you are dissatisfied with is UL-Listed, domestic *Builder Grade* receptacles that cost 75 cents at the box store, use "backstabs", and are sold loose in bins.  Yes, it's true, they're not the greatest outlets.   They're designed to last til closing.

However, the outlet you actually want - and many of use for same reasons - is the "Spec Grade" outlet, sold in the next bin over for $3.  It is sold in a box not loose typically, is much better built overall. It also has better features such as "screw-and-clamp" to side-wire, and "self-grounding" when installed in a metal box.

The Amazon sales model is for 3rd party sellers to sit in a faraway country with whom we have limited commercial treaties but not full legal treaties, such that they can make money but are beyond the reach of enforcement.  They bulk purchase very cheaply made counterfeits (made to look like good product) off the Alibaba wholesale website, have that stuff boxed and barcoded for Amazon, and ship it and other items by the container load to Amazon warehouses all over the country.  Thus it fulfills with Prime, and many Amazon fans mistake "Prime shipping" with "Amazon's own good product". In fact it is sold by 3rd parties.

This, plus contamination of Amazon's own product due to their allowing "commingling" (which destroys chain of custody)... is why we advise against buying electrical gear on Amazon or other mail order sites.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty familiar with all that. Which brings me back to my original dilemma. Are there decora style spec/commercial/industrial grade outlets that are tamper resistant (current code I understand, and I know the linked ones are not), and not incredibly expensive? I would have bought at a big box store if I could find them. There seems to be the Leviton Decora Plus, but that's over $6.50/ea.

Comment: @user11015833 shrug, prices are crazy right now because of shortages and you just added that TR requirement out of the blue. (the Amazon outlets you linked are not TR).  Decora is a deluxe/upscale style so one might expect them to charge more for it, even though it's just plastic lol.  Shopping assistance isn't really our format here.